# Building MVC 4 application on a TFS 2012 build server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tfs

I have a TFS 2012 server that acts as both the default controller and build agent. On this box is also installed VS 2012. I am using Visual Studio 2010 from my developer box to check in asp.net MVC 4.0 code. The check in goes fine, but if I try to build the application by calling the Queue new build function I get an error

```
The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotationsExtensions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have installed MVC 3 and 4 on the Build server and have checked that the c:\Program files x86.... path has the necessary dlls. Still I get this error.

Any help appreciated in fixing this if TFS 2012 can actually build .net 40 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the DAE extenstion:
http://nuget.org/packages/DataAnnotationsExtensions/1.1.0.0

Instead of "installing DAE on the build server"  It should come down with NuGet.
Nuget is PART OF THE TFS BUILD SYSTEM ALREADY!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/05/10/using-nuget-with-tfs-build-automation.aspx